# Deploy Fuse Camel Project on EAP

Tags: jboss, apache-camel, jbossfuse, fuseesb

I build a simple Camel Project with a SOAP Web Service that writes a file and sends the response: it's packaged as bundle and I deployed it successfully on Karaf, you can find the source here

[Firefox Send](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9808967a49090a595bd0876fca1b92b520181005101828/d5ffe7)

Then I'd like to convert this project in a WAR module and deploy it on Fuse on EAP: following these instructions

[Apache Camel: Tutorial on using Camel in a Web Application](http://camel.apache.org/tutorial-on-using-camel-in-a-web-application.html)

I modified (in pom.xml) bundle -> war, I moved applicationContext.xml under src/main/webapp, and I created a web.xml with the Spring context loader: when I install the WAR I see (on server logs) that the Camel route is started but the SOAP WS isn't exposed

```
10:03:40,981 INFO  [org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) Apache Camel 2.15.1 (CamelContext: camelId) is starting

10:03:40,994 INFO  [org.apache.camel.management.ManagedManagementStrategy] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) JMX is enabled

10:03:41,120 INFO  [org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) Loaded 197 type converters

10:03:41,339 INFO  [org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) AllowUseOriginalMessage is enabled. If access to the original message is not needed, then its recommended to turn this option off as it may improve performance.

10:03:41,339 INFO  [org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html

10:03:41,370 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) Creating Service {http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans}CamelHelloWorldService from WSDL: classpath:wsdl/Hello.wsdl

10:03:41,732 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) Setting the server's publish address to be /CamelHelloWorld

10:03:41,764 INFO  [org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) Route: route2 started and consuming from: Endpoint[cxf://bean:helloWorldEndpointId]

10:03:41,764 INFO  [org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) Total 1 routes, of which 1 is started.

10:03:41,764 INFO  [org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) Apache Camel 2.15.1 (CamelContext: camelId) started in 0.783 seconds

10:03:41,764 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2131 ms

10:03:41,826 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 2) JBAS015859: Deployed "camel-hello-world-0.0.21-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name : "camel-hello-world-0.0.21-SNAPSHOT.war")
```

To be honest I see this exception too

```
10:03:39,711 WARN  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) Ignored XML validation warning: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 419; SchemaLocation: schemaLocation value = ' http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf-spring.xsd' must have even number of URI's.

at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:196)

at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.warning(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:97)

at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:386)

at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:322)
```

but I think it's only a warning.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The SOAP WS seems exposed, in logs i see:
`10:03:41,732 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) Setting the server's publish address to be /CamelHelloWorld
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'must have even number of URI's' exception is because you have a superfluous entry for `camel-cxf-spring.xsd` at the end of the `xsi:schemaLocation`.

You may find it better to base your code on the [Camel Tomcat CXF example](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-cxf-tomcat) as it demonstrates how to set up `CXFServlet` in web.xml. You'll need this is you want the CXF consumer to work. E.g like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webservices/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If you're using Fuse on EAP 7.0 or 7.1, you can avoid the Spring `ContextLoaderListener` and `CXFServlet` as the app server takes care of bootstrapping Spring & CXF for you. There's an example project [here](https://github.com/wildfly-extras/wildfly-camel-examples/tree/master/camel-cxf-jaxws).